# UICollectionView in second tab causing UICollectionView in first tab to crash app

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller

I am a beginner currently working on my first IOS app. In my apps home page, I have a top menu bar that consists of a horizontal collection view with 3 cell pages (3 tabs). Inside each of these cells are 3 collection views displaying objects from my database. I also have a UITabBarController with 3 tabs at the bottom.

I am trying to add another collection view in the second tab. However, as soon as I change the second tabs view controller class to of type uiCollectionViewController, the app will crash when I tab back to the first (home page) and try scrolling with my horizontal collection view. The bug only comes when the second tab is changed to of type UICollectionView.

I apologize if this hard to understand. 
I have been stuck on this for a while, so I had to try.

Thank you!!

Here is a photo of the error and my code when it crashes:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the issue was here..

I was providing the same layout parameter to two different collection views when setting them up as items in my tab bar controller.

```
Let layout1 = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

Let firstController = FirstCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout1)

Let layout2 = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

Let secondController = 
SecondCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout2)
```

This implementation fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a new `NSIndexPath` and cast it into `IndexPath`. You can directly make a new `IndexPath` and use it.

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: menuIndex, section: 0)
```

Lastly, make sure that the value of your `menuIndex` is less than the `count` of your datasource array.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with your delegate method. In your controller, in collection view delegate method 'cellForItem' try adding check if method is called for correct collection view. i.e. If you are on one tab then add check in method 'cellForItem' to confirm if it;s the same collection view.

Comment: Hello Nik, thank you for responding. By checking did you mean something like this? -- if indexPath.item == 1 && self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell.. I understand the logic Im just not sure how to execute exactly.

Comment: @AlexConstancio, check should be,
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
      cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == myCollectionView {
      //return appropriate cell.
   }
}